# Join two files using awk

Tags: file, join, awk

I have two files like shown below which are tab-delimited:

file A

```
chr1   123 aa b c d
chr1   234 a  b c d
chr1   345 aa b c d
chr1   456 a  b c d
....
```

file B

```
xxxx  abcd    chr1   123    aa    c    d    e
yyyy  defg    chr1   345    aa    e    f    g
...
```

I want to join the two files based on 3 columns with "chr1", "123" and "aa"  and add first two columns from file B to file A, such that output looks as shown below:
output:

```
chr1   123    aa    b    c    d    xxxx    abcd
chr1   234    a     b    c    d
chr1   345    aa    b    c    d    yyyy    defg
chr1   456    a    b    c    d
```

Could anyone help to do this in awk. If possible using awk oneliners?

Comment: [What have you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one approach using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3,$4]=$1OFS$2;next}{$6=a[$1,$2];print}' OFS='\t' fileb filea
chr1    123     a    b    c     xxxx    abcd
chr1    234     a    b    c 
chr1    345     a    b    c     yyyy    defg
chr1    456     a    b    c
```

Explanation:

```
NR==FNR             # current recond num match the file record num i.e in filea
a[$3,$4]=$1OFS$2    # Create entry in array with fields 3 and 4 as the key
next                # Grab the next line (don't process the next block)
$6=a[$1,$2]         # Assign the looked up value to field 6 (+rebuild records)  
print               # Print the current line & the matching entry from fileb ($6)

OFS='\t'            # Seperate each field with a single TAB on output
```

**Edit:**

For the 3 field problem you simple add the extra field:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3,$4,$5]=$1OFS$2;next}{$6=a[$1,$2,$3];print}' OFS='\t' fileb filea
chr1    123    aa     b      c     xxxx     abcd
chr1    234    a      b      c  
chr1    345    aa     b      c     yyyy     defg
chr1    456    a      b      c
```

Comment: i have modified the original problem. Coudl you provide solution for that.

Comment: Thanks. I was adding the extra field in the following way which went wrong:awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3,$4,$5]=$1OFS$2OFS$3;next}{$6=a[$1,$2];print}' OFS='\t' fileb filea.

Comment: +1 but you should set FS as well in case there's any spaces within the fields. Stunning misunderstanding of the script by the OP though!

Comment: @sudo_O fileb is very huge file and when im trying to run the code it gives the error: "more_nodes: nextfree: can't allocate 6400 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)".  Could you modify the script so that fileb is read in chunks to solve the memory problem ?

Comment: @user1779730 this is what the command `split` does. Read `man split`.

Comment: Thanks. By using split we get 'n' files and the above awk script has to be run on 'n' files separately. WOuld it be possible to incorporate the split command into the above awk script so that fileb is split automatically and run on each individual file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join`, but the pipeline gets so complicated it might be easier to switch to a more powerful language like Perl.

```
join -11 -21 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.4,2.5 \
     <(sed 's/ \+/:/' fileA | sort) \
     <(sed 's/ \+/:/' fileB | sort) \
 | join -11 -22 -a1 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,2.5,2.6 \
     - <(sed 's/ \+\([^ ]\+\) \+\([^ ]\+\)/ \1:\2/' fileC | sort -k2) \
 | sed 's/:/ /'
```

Perl solution, using a hash to remember all the information:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

#             key_start  key_end  keep_from  output
my %files = (A => [0,      1,      2,       [0 .. 3]],
             B => [0,      1,      2,       [-2, -1]],
             C => [1,      2,      3,       [-2, -1]],
            );

my %hash;

for my $file (keys %files) {
    open my $FH, '<', "file$file" or die "file$file: $!";
    while (<$FH>) {
        my @fields = split;
        $hash{"@fields[$files{$file}[0], $files{$file}[1]]"}{$file}
            = [ @fields[$files{$file}[2] .. $#fields] ];
    }
}

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    print $key, join(' ', q(),
                     grep defined, map {
                         @{ $hash{$key}{$_} }[@{ $files{$_}[-1] }]
                     } sort keys %files), "\n";
}
```

Comment: @user1779730: Perl solution added.